# _this.setState is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

currently learning about react-native and trying out to code a few things I came across this error:

> _this.setState is not a funtion.(In '_this.setState({myState: createSignature()})','_this.setState' is undefined)

I have routing and get my about page like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux'
import Moment from 'react-moment';
import EventEmitter from "react-native-md5";
import md5 from "react-native-md5";

const devID = 0000;
const authKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

function createSignature(){
    var ut = new Date();
    var time = <Moment utc={true} element={Text} format="YYYYMMDDHHmmss">{ut}</Moment>;
    var signaturePre = devID + "createsession" + authKey + time;
    return md5.hex_md5(signaturePre);
}

const About = () => {
   const goToHome = () => {
      Actions.home()
   }   

state = {
      myState: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,'
   }
   updateState = () => {
      this.setState({ myState: createSignature() })
   }
      return (
         <View>
            <Text onPress = {this.updateState}>
               {this.state.myState}
            </Text>
            <TouchableOpacity style = {{ margin: 128 }} onPress = {goToHome}>
                <Text>This is ABOUT</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>  
        </View>
  )
}
export default About
```

I don't want someone to just give the solution I want to understand what I'm missing I have also tried using **Props** for it but this resulted in the same error.

The error hints to line 29

```
return(
```

Comment: Since you are asking for clues: You need to ask yourself what `this` refers to in this case.

Comment: @Chris thanks i'm gonna check again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `About` component is a functional component and hence don't have the `this` property and state. Create it by extending `React.Component`

```
class About extends React.Component {
   goToHome = () => {
      Actions.home()
   }   

   state = {
      myState: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,'
   }
   updateState = () => {
      this.setState({ myState: createSignature() })
   }
      return (
         <View>
            <Text onPress = {this.updateState}>
               {this.state.myState}
            </Text>
            <TouchableOpacity style = {{ margin: 128 }} onPress = {this.goToHome}>
                <Text>This is ABOUT</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>  
        </View>
  )
}
export default About
```

Comment: I understand better but extends works for classes no? shouldn't it become: `class About extends React.Component {`

Comment: Yes it should be a class, that was a typo from from side

Comment: Well however using a class makes the routing not work as I get the error: **can't find variable: goToHome**

Comment: You won't since that also becomes a class function and should be called like this.goToHome as you see in my answer

Comment: using this.goToHome gives me syntax error of unexpected token

Comment: have you made goToHome a class function and not const goToHome = () => {}